# Is there a way to download videos from Channel 9?

Tags: video, download, streaming, silverlight

I am trying to download this video:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Contract-Oriented-Programming-and-Spec

But the WMV link doesn't work if you click "Save As". jDownloader also doesn't see anything. I can watch it but is there a way to download them?

I remember downloading them last year without a problem, not sure what they changed.

Comment: just fetch the source file... http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/ch9/0/E2ESpecSharp_2MB_ch9.wmv

Comment: Higher quality version: http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/ch9/0/E2ESpecSharp_ch9.wmv

Comment: Thanks but I think that's lower quality 200mb vs 1.3gb.

Comment: Now that Channel9 is history, you can (still) download the clips via [this index page](https://walkingcat.github.io/ch9-index/) whereas the new websites on docs.microsoft.com don't seem to offer any way to download and yt-dlp as well as youtube-dl seem to be useless for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the video, choose "Copy Link Location", and paste that in your browser.

Shorcut: [here's the link](http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/ch9/0/E2ESpecSharp_2MB_ch9.wmv)

Comment: I right clicked the video but it only opens a menu that says "silverlight", nothing else.

Comment: You must be using IE. Try in Firefox or Chrome perhaps. If not, the link I gave you should still work

Comment: I tried IE and Chrome, both had same result.

Comment: That's interesting...if it doesn't work in Firefox, I'm stumped.

Comment: It's ok, I downloaded t he video. But how did you get that link yourself? :)

Comment: Right-clicking in Firefox. If that didn't work (if it had been a Flash video or something), I would have waded through the page source code until I found the video's source (or simply chosen to "inspect element" and find the source from there - but in my experience many publishers who use Flash try to hide videos better than that)

Comment: Thanks I will try that next time. I only wanted to download this video.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this site to download.

http://dayngo.com/channel9

It has latest content and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **youtube-dl** which is a command line tool to download videos from youtube and some other sites.
This tool works fine for channel9 Urls.
for e.g `youtube-dl {video or playlist URL}`